# How to fix a hollow ceramic shower shelf

Tags: shower, tile

Our shelf in the shower cracked off four big pieces but the bottom of the shelf stayed intact. Now we have a jagged bowl shaped shelf left collecting water whenever we shower. Any recommendations on how I can keep the shards level while they cure? Should I fill the hole with foam of some kind and then put epoxy glue on the shards and hope that the foam doesn't move too much until they're cured?

Comment: You could try just filling the bowl with self-leveling compound, and then using a concrete sealer for waterproofness.

Comment: what is preventing you from replacing the shelf?